# Does the Admission committee care about my google scholar or related profiles?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions

I am in the process of applying for a US PhD program in the TOP50, majoring in Chemical Engineering. On the admission websites, I was asked to mention the number or list of all the papers I have published in my undergraduate study. I have about 20 publications, some of which are not significantly related to my target graduate research area (or I have insignificant contribution <50%). So If I just list some of the most important publications to that I have a significant contribution (>50%) to the admission profile, will the committee care about others that have been presented in my personal profiles, and can these negatively affect my potential to get the acceptance?

Comment: I was on an admissions committee in PhD program in Math for many years: We never looked at anything which is not mentioned in the official application file.

Comment: You have around 20 publications _as an undergraduate_!? Wow. I would certainly mention all of them, why leave any out?

Comment: I also want to list all of them lol. However some of them are not really related to my main research area and I do not have a significant contribution to them. I obtained the authorships of those articles due to my collaboration with some sub-groups for 3 years in terms of writing and revising the manuscripts. Some senior researchers said that the large number of pubs may be a red flag to many universities so I am really afraid to add them to my CV :(((

Comment: Are these all peer reviewed in legitimate journals and at least of minimal scholarly quality?

Comment: Absolutely, all of them are peer reviewed and indexed by scopus or WoS

Comment: Unfortunately, indexing by Scopus or WoS does not guarantee quality/lack of predatory nature, and for some journals peer review is just "peer review". It's hard to judge without actually reviewing your publications, but I do wonder if senior researchers warning about the numbers are actually gently warning you about the quality.

Comment: I agree. So that's why I wonder that if I just list some papers that I believe are the most qualified, will the committee care about the others that have been listed in my Scopus or google Scholar? Btw thank you very much for your comment <3.

Comment: I don't know if this helps but I usually split my CV publications into 'key publications' (either highly relevant to the role or I'm first/senior author) that I want to reader to focus on and 'other publications' where I can say have less of a meaningful contribution or they aren't relevant.  Everybody has this problem to some extent.

Comment: Maybe detailing your role in each paper would be helpful---say in your CV? That way you explicitly state the percentage contribution and what you did. Was it just lab help in some and primary author in others, e.g.? Just be open and honest about all. That would easily explain the quantity.

Answer (score 6):

It's really impossible to give a 100% definitive answer about how an admissions committee would feel about all those publications. My gut reaction is that they would be impressed but skeptical. 20 papers over 3 years is *very* productive for anyone, let alone an undergraduate student. I suspect that your professor (who advised you not to list them all) is concerned that someone reading your application will assume you were involved in some unethical authorship-sharing ring - whether or not that is the case**.

Probably no-one will take the extra time and effort to search for and evaluate publications you don't list on your application. But obviously it is possible that someone *does* do that. I imagine that if someone did look you up, they would wonder why you didn't mention those extra publications. It might raise some questions.

If someone were to look up your publications specifically, the only reason that it might harm you is if they are in predatory journals or if there is clearly something *off*. Again, it's unlikely that someone would take the significant time and effort to evaluate each and every publication (and the journals they are in).

All that being said, if there is nothing sketchy about the publications, there is no reason not to list them, even if they are not the focus of your application. In my opinion, it's better to just explain your involvement in numerous projects than it is to appear to be "hiding" things on the off chance someone Google's your name.

** I won't comment on this too much but I do think it's worth addressing. How fast publications come out is field dependant and, to an extent, lab dependant. But, in my field, if a student showed up with ~7 publications per year over 3 years I would be very suspicious. It is *almost* impossible for a student to be involved in so many projects in a meaningful way. To me this sounds like a situation where everyone's name goes on every paper regardless of contribution. I'm not saying that this is the case, but it does set off my spidey senses.

Comment: +1. Corollary: OP should make sure that some (or all) of the letters come from supervisors or senior collaborators who can testify to the significance of the publications and what OP's contributions were. The application will be stronger if, for some of the publications, the letters describe this in specific detail.

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon what kinds of journals and how you got involved in   publication. Large number of publications without being a first author means sometime just adding your name on someone's work which is unethical but very less likely to be identified as noone else knows about it. Predatory journals may not help but harm. If publications are genuine works in non predatory journals considered by departments you are applying, generally it helps.